# Json .Net Deserialize

Tags: c#, .net, json, serialization, json.net

i need little help. I have type film which has some attributes. And i have list of this film(List). When i serialize it and save to file, i am unable to load and deserialize it(some type of Xaml error).
Here is json saved in file:

```
[
    {
        "cesta": "C:\\Users\\Kenny\\Videos\\[Glitch Hop or 110BPM]   Rogue   Night After Night [Monstercat Release].wmv",
        "jmeno": "Test",
        "serie": "0",
        "hodnoceni": "",
        "herci": "",
        "rok": 0,
        "dil": 0,
        "obrazek": "file:///C:/Users/Kenny/Pictures/Pozadi­/1.jpg"
    },
    {
        "cesta": "C:\\Users\\Kenny\\Videos\\[EDM]   Laszlo x WRLD   You  Me [Monstercat Release].mp4",
        "jmeno": "Test2",
        "serie": "0",
        "hodnoceni": "",
        "herci": "",
        "rok": 0,
        "dil": 0,
        "obrazek": "file:///C:/Users/Kenny/Pictures/Pozadi/1.jpg"
    }
]
```

And here is code to deserialize it:

```
List<Film> temp = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<Film>>(json, new FilmConverter());
```

Thanks for help.

Comment: What error do you have?

Comment: @sławomir-rosiek: `A first chance exception of type 'System.Windows.Markup.XamlParseException' occurred in PresentationFramework.dll`

Comment: Can you post the code of `FilmConverter`? That error sounds completely unrelated. My guess is that it is coming from somewhere else.

Comment: That FilmConverter was just attempt, it is not working even without it.

Comment: JSON is not XAML, and the two are not even related.  If you're getting a XamlParseException then the problem is not in Json.Net.  In fact, if you replace the above line of code with `var temp = new List<Film>();` I would bet that your error still remains.  I would take a look at your XAML.  There is probably a syntax error in there somewhere.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The best way to use JSON.Net is to create a class definition that describes your JSON data and use `JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<>` method to deserialize JSON into objects.

For example:

```
public class FilmInfo
{
    [JsonProperty("cesta")]
    public string Path { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("rok")]
    public int Year { get; set; }

    // other properties
    public string jmeno { get; set; }
    public string serie { get; set; }
    public string hodnoceni { get; set; }
    public int dil { get; set; }
    public string obrazek { get; set; }
};

static void Main(string[] args)
{
    var json = @"
    [
        {
            'cesta': 'C:\\Users\\Kenny\\Videos\\[Glitch Hop or 110BPM]   Rogue   Night After Night [Monstercat Release].wmv',
            'jmeno': 'Test',
            'serie': '0',
            'hodnoceni': '',
            'herci': '',
            'rok': 0,
            'dil': 0,
            'obrazek': 'file:///C:/Users/Kenny/Pictures/Pozadi­/1.jpg'
        },
        {
            'cesta': 'C:\\Users\\Kenny\\Videos\\[EDM]   Laszlo x WRLD   You  Me [Monstercat Release].mp4',
            'jmeno': 'Test2',
            'serie': '0',
            'hodnoceni': '',
            'herci': '',
            'rok': 0,
            'dil': 0,
            'obrazek': 'file:///C:/Users/Kenny/Pictures/Pozadi/1.jpg'
        }
    ]";

    var list = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<FilmInfo>>(json);
}
```

Comment: I have created .net fiddle link for your code: [link](https://dotnetfiddle.net/CWQSof)

Comment: Thanks, i did not notice, that i save to file BitmapImage, not path to it... But thanks a lot :)